# How to filter an array of JSON objects to be used in a table view?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm getting JSON data from an API and parsing that data in objects, which are then simply stored in an array of objects. The objects themselves contain data about articles from a newspaper. However, I need to filter that data. Some of the objects I'm getting from my JSON actually have no article content because they are pictures and not articles (i.e. some of the "nodes" from the API's JSON have content that I don't want to see in my table view).

In my JSON-parsing function, I've tried to make it so that the parsed object will only get added to the array of parsed objects if the character count of the "articleContent" variable is above 40. Here is what it looked like.

```
if issueElement.articleContent.characters.count > 40 {
    self.currentIssueObjects.addObject(issueElement)
}
```

However, this simply does not work. I get the typical "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error message (I don't get a specific line for the error). How can I make this work ? I'm essentially trying to prevent the array from having objects with empty articleContent, because then that screws up my table view (empty cells, duplicates, etc...).

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath code, and my JSON-parsing code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell else {

        print ("error: currentIssueTableView cell is not of class CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell, we will use EditorialsTableViewCell instead")
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditorialsTableViewCell
    }

    let currentIssueObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! IssueElement

        let title = currentIssueObject.title ?? ""

        let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(currentIssueObject.timeStamp))
        let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject) ?? "Date unknown"

    if let author = currentIssueObject.author {

        cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.text = author

    }

        let issueNumber = currentIssueObject.issueNumber ?? ""
        let volumeNumber = currentIssueObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

        let articleContent = currentIssueObject.articleContent ?? ""

        let nodeID = currentIssueObject.nodeID ?? 0

        cell.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.text = title



        cell.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.text = timeStampDateString

        if row == 0 {

            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false

            let imageURL = (currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(row) as! IssueElement).imageURL

            cell.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()

            cell.request?.cancel()

            if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL!) as? UIImage {
                cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.image = image
            } else {
                cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "reveal Image")
                cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL!).responseImage() { response in
                    if response.result.error == nil && response.result.value != nil {
                        self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: response.request!.URLString)
                        cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.image = response.result.value
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }
            cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.hidden = false
        }

        else {
            cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.hidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

JSON-parsing code:

```
func populateCurrentIssue() {
    if populatingCurrentIssue {
        return
    }

    populatingCurrentIssue = true

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.backgroundColor = goldenWordsYellow
    self.cellLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Issue).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

                var nodeIDArray : [Int]

                if (JSON .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)) {

                    for node in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        let nodeIDValue = node.0
                        var lastItem : Int = 0

                        self.nodeIDArray.addObject(nodeIDValue)

                        if let issueElement : IssueElement = IssueElement(title: "Could not retrieve title", nodeID: 0, timeStamp: 0, imageURL: "init", author: "Author not found", issueNumber: "Issue # error", volumeNumber: "Volume # error", articleContent: "Could not retrieve article content", coverImageInteger: "init", coverImage: UIImage()) {

                            issueElement.title = node.1["title"] as! String
                            issueElement.nodeID = Int(nodeIDValue)!

                            let timeStampString = node.1["revision_timestamp"] as! String
                            issueElement.timeStamp = Int(timeStampString)!

                            issueElement.imageURL = String(node.1["image_url"])

                            if let author = node.1["author"] as? String {
                                issueElement.author = author
                            }
                            if let issueNumber = node.1["issue_int"] as? String {
                                issueElement.issueNumber = issueNumber
                            }
                            if let volumeNumber = node.1["volume_int"] as? String {
                                issueElement.volumeNumber = volumeNumber
                            }

                            if let articleContent = node.1["html_content"] as? String {
                                issueElement.articleContent = articleContent
                            }

                            issueElement.coverImageInteger = String(node.1["cover_image"]) // addition specific to the Current Issue View Controller

                            lastItem = self.currentIssueObjects.count


                          print(issueElement.nodeID)

                            if issueElement.articleContent.characters.count > 40 {
                                self.currentIssueObjects.addObject(issueElement)
                                print(issueElement.nodeID)
                            }

                            // Sorting with decreasing timestamp from top to bottom.
                            let timestampSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
                            self.currentIssueObjects.sortUsingDescriptors([timestampSortDescriptor])

                            // Placing the object with coverImage

                            let coverImageSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "coverImageInteger", ascending: false)
                            self.currentIssueObjects.sortUsingDescriptors([coverImageSortDescriptor])

                            let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.currentIssueObjects.count).map {
                                NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.currentIssueTableView.reloadData()

                    self.cellLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.cellLoadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

                }
            }
        }

        self.populatingCurrentIssue = false
}
}
```

Comment: I think you get the error because you are unwrapping `imageURL!` when parsing your JSON file. Are you sure that each node does have a imageURL? If not you'll get this error. Try wrapping it in an `if let` to avoid this.

Comment: Maybe stop force-unwrapping optionals if you want to know when they are nil…

Comment: I hange the issueElement.imageURL statement to an if let, and now my app is building properly. However, I'm still getting empty cells in my tableView.